# mysql from_unixtime(cds1.field_id_34, '%d/%m/%y') if `date` is null select `-`

Tags: mysql

The select below will return title and date.

```
SELECT t1.title, from_unixtime(cds1.field_id_34, '%d/%m/%y') AS s1_date
```

So all is correct but if `cds1.field_id_34` is null it returns 01/01/1970. How can I set it up so if `cds1.field_id_34` is null it would return `-` instead of `01/01/1970`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     select  if(cds1.field_id_34=null,'-',cds1.field_id_34) from TableName
```